# Problem about bridge hand distribution

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving, card-games

Discrete Mathematics 8ed, R Johnsonbaugh, problem 6.5.28: "Find the probability of obtaining a bridge hand with 5–4–2–2 distribution, that is, five cards in one suit, four cards in another suit, and two cards in each of the other two suits."

Answer: $\frac{4C(13,5)\times3C(13,4)C(13,2)^2}{C(52,13)}$

I understand why there's a 4 in the numerator, it's because we can start picking 5 cards from 13 from any of the 4 suits. Then the 3 is there supposedly to say that, "ok now we can pick 4 cards form 13 from the other 3 suits", right?

But why is there *not* a "2" in the numerator, saying "and we can pick 2 cards from 13 from the third suit (of which we have 2 options)"? (In this case we'd finish the numerator simply by the factor $C(13,2)$ which would say "pick 2 cards from 13 in the last remaining suit, of which we have 1 option.")

Comment: 5 spades, 4 hearts, 2 clubs and 2 diamonds is equivalent to 5 spades, 4 hearts, 2 diamonds and 2 clubs.

Comment: Once the first and second suits are chosen, the last two suits are automatically determined. There is no order among the last two suits (because you get two cards of each).

Comment: @GabrielRomon I see, and if the problem's distribution instead was 5-4-2-3, would that lead to "ordering among the last two suits"?  Would the numerator then be $4C(13,5) \times3C(13,4) \times C(13,2) \times C(13,3)$?

Comment: No, in a 5-4-1-3 distribution, you would need $~4C(13,5) \times 3C(13,4) \times 2C(13,1) \times C(13,3).~$  Note that I changed your comment because $~5 + 4 + 2 + 3 \neq 13.~$  Also, note that with $~4~$ distinct numbers (i.e. 5-4-1-3), you do have to have the $~2~$ coefficient in front of the $~C(13,1)~$ factor.